# align list items to top of ul container

Tags: html, css, user-interface, html-lists

The `li` tag in my `ul` doesn't start from top. Instead it starts from the bottom.

I want to have all the images starting from top and all the labels of those images should start 10px below images.

**Important:** images and text should be center-aligned within li.

Final output should be something like below image even when labels are bigger:

[image]

Any help is highly appreciated.

Code goes here: https://jsfiddle.net/srshah23/suctrnuq/

```css
.cul {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0px auto 0;
}
.cli {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10%;
  padding: 0px 25px 0;
  background-size: 46px;
}
.cli .img {
  background: url("https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/3906f6fa3d7c00158d98abe7540054c8/?default=&s=64") no-repeat;
  width: 46px;
  height: 46px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul class="cul">
    <li class="cli">
      <div class="img"></div>
      <div>PRETTY LONG TEXT ABCDEFG</div>
    </li>
    <li class="cli">
      <div class="img"></div>
      <div>TEXTUAL PLANNING</div>
    </li>
    <li class="cli">
      <div class="img"></div>
      <div>PRETTY TEXT</div>
    </li>
    <li class="cli">
      <div class="img"></div>
      <div>RANDOM TEXT ABC</div>
    </li>
    <li class="cli">
      <div class="img"></div>
      <div>MEDIUM TEXT</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/tjbaezid/mjeb8o6q/1/  so are you looking something like this. but also like that image you share

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For the alignment you want, add `vertical-align: top` and `text-align: center` to `li.cli`.

For margin between image and text, change `margin: 0 auto` to `margin: 0 auto 10px` in `.img`.

[revised fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/suctrnuq/3/)

---

Additional info:

Your list items have `display: inline-block`. The `vertical-align` property applies to inline-level elements and the default value is `baseline`.

You'll notice in your code (especially if you apply a border) that each list item is aligned to the baseline of the container ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/suctrnuq/2/)). Override the default with `vertical-align: top`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align

Comment: vertical-align: top works for me!
My list has been placed to top

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you you want something like this. If not tell me I will change it - And I create an extra class for the text div name it 'txt' and I have comment out on css so you will easily understand where I have changes [Live Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tjbaezid/mjeb8o6q/2/)

```css
.cul {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  /* remove the last 0 from here */
}

.cli {
  display: inline-table;
  /*change this to inline-table */
  width: 10%;
  padding: 0px 25px 10px;
  /*replace last 0 with 10px when window resize And remove the back ground size */
}

.cli .img {
  background: url("https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/3906f6fa3d7c00158d98abe7540054c8/?default=&s=64") no-repeat;
  width: 46px;
  height: 46px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.txt {
  /*add this css for the gap and center text */
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul class="cul">
    <li class="cli">
      <div class="img"></div>
      <div class="txt">PRETTY LONG TEXT ABCDEFG</div>
    </li>
    <li class="cli">
      <div class="img"></div>
      <div class="txt">TEXTUAL PLANNING</div>
    </li>
    <li class="cli">
      <div class="img"></div>
      <div class="txt">PRETTY TEXT</div>
    </li>
    <li class="cli">
      <div class="img"></div>
      <div class="txt">RANDOM TEXT ABC</div>
    </li>
    <li class="cli">
      <div class="img"></div>
      <div class="txt">MEDIUM TEXT</div>
    </li>
  </ul>

</div>
```