# un-ordered list alignment from top-left instead of bottom-left

Tags: css, html

So, I cannot figure out how to align the items in my list the way I want them to be aligned. I have them displayed as inline-block, but I also want the list elements to be aligned from the top-left instead what looks like bottom-left (default).

[Browser display of list elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2MT5.png)

The CSS code I have so far is:

```
#courses ul { 
    list-style-type: none;
}
#courses li { 
    display: inline-block;
    border: 2px solid #000000;
    width: 300px;
    margin: 5px;
    background-color: white;
}
```

Comment: Ah, it was vertical-align: top;

Comment: `vertical-align:top` more likely.

Comment: I know there is a dupe, I just can't find it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [align list items to top of ul container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39811756/align-list-items-to-top-of-ul-container)

Comment: @PaigeMeinke default is baseline which is why the issue exist

Comment: @Huangism I misread the question, I thought that was what he wanted, whoops.

Answer (score 0):

The method that corrected it was:`

vertical-align: top;`

Comment: A little research would of answered your question and if you are going to answer your own question, at least put some effort in it and explain your answer